Problem related to useNavigate hook in react
all pretty new to the react/express journey. I am rn making a todo app with google oauth 2.0 with passport.js right now all i want is to navigate from "localhost:5173/login" to "localhost:3000/api/auth/" which is the route which i have provided for google auth
Login.jsx
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const authGoogle = () => {
    navigate("/api/google");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>This is the Login Page</h1>
      <button
        className="bg-green-400 p-2 hover:bg-green-800"
        onClick={authGoogle}
      >
        google
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;

Routes
import express from "express";
import passport from "passport";

import {
  deleteTodo,
  getAllTodo,
  postTodo,
  updateTodo,
  updateTodoData,
} from "../controller/todocontroller.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.route("/get").get(getAllTodo);
router.route("/add").post(postTodo);
router.route("/delete").post(deleteTodo);
router.route("/update/:id").put(updateTodo);
router.route("/updatetodo").put(updateTodoData);

export default router;

router.get("/google",passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['profile', 'email']}));


index.js(middlewares and stuff)
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import routes from "./routes/todoroutes.js";
import passport from "passport";
import cors from "cors";
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from "passport-google-oauth2";

const app = express();

dotenv.config();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  cors({
    // Apply CORS middleware
    origin: "http://localhost:3000", // Adjust this to match your frontend's origin
    credentials: true,
  })
);

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID =
  "16448801074-1pod7pl7ui3egk03ik9v9isp6oa86h3m.apps.googleusercontent.com";
const CLIENT_SECRET = "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";

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/google/callback",
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    function (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      return done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

app.use("/api", routes);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Connected at port ${PORT}`);
});

vite config
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server:{
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
      },
      '/google': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000/api/google',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/google/, '')
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [react()],
})

I have also tried using the proxy for vite in this case but its not working for me while all the other routes which i am fetching through axios are working which the former is not.
I have tried using the url directly into navigate("locahost:3000/api/google")

Please add a description of what's the error you're getting. And also, can you add your router config?

error : No routes matched location "/google" when i press the login button
Router config :
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={<Todo todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos} {...props} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="todolistupdate"
            element={<TodolistUpdate {...props} />}
          />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>


The problem has been solved
I have used windows.open("http://localhost:3000/google", "_self") as axios/fetch requests cannot be made for google authetication. Even navigate does not work in this situation
https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/11vh7ii/cors_issue_with_google_oauth/
